# Unity project folders missing

Tags: unity-game-engine

i found an old unity project but the "standard project folders" such as

"ProjectSettings"
"UserSettings"
"Packages"
ecc.

are missing.

[here it is the folder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kspqh.png)

the only folder that i have is "Assets". is there a way to find the missing folders?
maybe they are stored somewhere else in the disk and linked to the project? (i don't know if it's possible)

the project in this state is corrupted and not usable, is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new project, and replacing the "Assets" folder of the old project with that of the newly created project.
Unity has changed the structures of its projects over the years, so it is normal that after many years you cannot open it.
When you open the project with the old "Assets" folder, remember that you will have many errors to solve: you will have to add all the packages you entered, and modify the opsoleto code.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the project is only 8 months old i believe.

Comment: Ah OK. It is likely that they are not present, but it is unlikely that they are in other locations. Try using my answer anyway, and if it helps you, you can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Unfortunately this solutions does not work because level scenes are missing, therefore the entire project is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the folder further, and saw that there are actually no normal assets such as scripts, images or audio in the "Assets" folder. Without those you can't get it back.
I am sorry.
I write another answer because the first one is valid for all cases where the "Assets" folder is intact.
You can decide which one looks best for you.